# Textarea placeholder not showing up on mobile

Tags: html, textarea

I have this code:

```
<textarea #newRowInput class="input" [focus]="(this.deviceService.os == 'windows' || this.deviceService.device == 'unknown') ? true : false"
 data-tab="1" tabindex="1" dir="auto" spellcheck="true" placeholder="{{ 'NoteBook.TypeDataText' }}"></textarea>
```

It works well when browsing on a pc (tested with chrome), but on mobile (also with chrome) there is no text in the placeholder. Also tried hardcoded text in the placeholder, and nothing.

Any solution?

Thanks

Comment: Might be that #newRowInput that you have there. Should that be the ID of the element?

Comment: @BillyMoat yes.

Comment: So it should be id='newRowInput'

Comment: @BillyMoat Sorry i didn't uderstand you, it is a local var, so it needs to be the way it is.

Comment: Okay, I'm not familiar with that. Try removing it and see if it works as expected. Worth a shot.

Comment: @BillyMoat It is an angular application, and this var is a must for me.. Thanks anyway